# Prevent app from loading explicit intent every onResume

Tags: android, android-intent

So I have Activity **A** and Activity **B**. **A** is the main screen of the app, and from this activity i can open **B**. Inside B the user inputs some data that gets sent through an intent back to activity A, then the data is displayed on the screen.

I have noted that while the intent works perfectly, every time I re-open the app on activity A there is an exact copy of the data sent in the last Intent.

onResume of activity **A** (reciever and displayer of the data)

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String name = intent.getStringExtra("name");
        String path = intent.getStringExtra("path");

        setAttrs(name, path);
    }
```

This is the intent that sends data from **B** to **A**, the intent is binded on an OnClick listener

```
send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                name = mEditText.getText().toString();

                Intent intent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("name", nameFile);
                intent.putExtra("path", outputFile);
                startActivity(intent);


            }
        });
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into using `startActivityForResult()` from `Activity` **A**.  In `Activity` **B** you then call `setResult()` and provide an `Intent` which is sent back to `Activity` **A**.  In `Activity` **A** you'll implement `onActivityResult()` to process the result.

Comment: You're very welcome, glad you were able to get it working.